# Boost upgrade_to_unique_lock compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I'm writing an app using Boost.Thread. Unfortunatelly, after moving new version to the 'production' environment I can't compile the project. `g++` says:

```
/usr/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp: In constructor 
    ‘boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<Mutex>::upgrade_to_unique_lock
    (boost::upgrade_lock<Mutex>&) [with Mutex = boost::shared_mutex]’:
worker.cpp:34:69: instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:926:48: error: call of overloaded ‘move(
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex>&)’ is ambiguous
/usr/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:926:48: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/move/move.hpp:294:86: note: typename boost::move_detail
    ::disable_if<boost::has_move_emulation_enabled<T>, T&>::type boost::move(T&)
    [with T = boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex>, typename boost::move_detail
    ::disable_if<boost::has_move_emulation_enabled<T>, T&>::type = boost
    ::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex>&]
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:44:110: note: typename boost
    ::enable_if<boost::is_convertible<T&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >,
    boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >::type boost::move(T&) [with T = boost
    ::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex>, typename boost::enable_if<boost
    ::is_convertible<T&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >, boost::detail
    ::thread_move_t<T> >::type = boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost
    ::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> >]
/usr/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp: In destructor ‘boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock
    <Mutex>::~upgrade_to_unique_lock() [with Mutex = boost::shared_mutex]’:
worker.cpp:34:69: instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:932:17: error: call of overloaded ‘move(boost
    ::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>&)’ is ambiguous
...
```

and so on and so forth.

I checked that dev and production environment have same libboost version (1.48).

Does anyone know what can be a reason? Which other libs/tools versions should i check/upgrade?

Comment: This is a known boost bug: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6141

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Boost 1.48 that appears to have been fixed in 1.49 according to [their bug tracker](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6141). There is an ambiguity if Boost.Move, which emulates C++11 move semantics, is used with Boost.Thread, which comes with its own move semantics emulators.

Considering that Boost 1.48 was released more than 2.5 years ago (in [November 2011](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_48_0.html)), you should consider upgrading to the newest release, which is currently Boost 1.55.